# how to sum up values of single dimentional array having same key in php

Tags: php, arrays

For example: if strArr is ["B:-1", "A:1", "B:3", "A:5"] then your program should return the string A:6,B:2.

Your final output string should return the keys in alphabetical order. Exclude keys that have a value of 0 after being summed up.
Examples
Input: array("X:-1", "Y:1", "X:-4", "B:3", "X:5")
Output: B:3,Y:1

Comment: This sounds like homework, and your question also doesn't show any effort at all.  Have you tried to solve this problem yourself yet?

Comment: Show us your best attempt (code) at solving your homework assignment, so we might be able to help you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple homework. You have to `explode` each pair into an array and to sum the values for each letter. Then sort (`ksort` by key), check and skip if there is a 0 into the produced array:

```
<?php
    $sums = array();
    $arr = array("X:-1", "Y:1", "X:-4", "B:3", "X:5");
    foreach ($arr as $key => $pair) {
        $pairArray = explode(":", $pair);
        (!array_key_exists($pairArray[0], $sums))
            ? $sums[$pairArray[0]] = (int)$pairArray[1]
            : $sums[$pairArray[0]] += (int)$pairArray[1];
    }

    print_r($sums);

    ksort($sums);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($sums as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != 0) {
            array_push($result, $key . ":" . $value);
        }
    }

    $result = implode(",", $result);
    echo $result;
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [X] => 0
    [Y] => 1
    [B] => 3
)

B:3,Y:1
```

Comment: this won't help the OP, or will it?